# Given a numpy array of strings, what is the best way to extract their indices based on a specific conditional slice of each string?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'm working with weather data, and I've been given dates corresponding to this data. I have a numpy array with every date, but I'd like to index based on the month. My current coding for this is the below, where I append the index value to the list with the respective month. Although this works, I feel as though this is messy and inefficient, and I'm looking for suggestions on how I could clean this up. For what I'm doing, I only really need the first and last index of each month, but this was the easiest way for me to think about it. I'm also fairly new to Python, so I'm only exploring the basic python functions.

for x in range(len(DATE_np)):

```
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '01':
    jan_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '02':
    feb_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '03':
    march_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '04':
    april_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '05':
    may_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '06':
    june_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '07':
    july_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '08':
    august_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '09':
    sept_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '10':
    october_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '11':
    nov_rains.append(x)
if DATE_np[x][4:6] == '12':
    december_rains.append(x)
```

Comment: Is `pandas` usage an option? Turning your `DATE_np` into a `pandas.DataFrame`, using `pd.to_datetime` to turn your `str` values to `pd.Timestamp`, and then using a `resample` with `'M'` or `'MS'` would be performant and straightforward.

Comment: I would create a dictionary `rainDict = {'01':jan_rains,'02':feb_rains}`... with the list stored then call `rainDict[Date_np['x'][4:6]].append(x)`

Comment: What is `DATE_np.shape` and `DATE_np.dtype`?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use pandas. The DATE_np array is a 1D array with 365 string values with YYYYMMDD format.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with numpy 1.23.0 (and available in the current `main`), `np.view` will not crash off-hand with non-contiguous arrays when changing to a different dtype size. What that means is that you will be able to do as follows:

```
mos = DATE_np[:, None].view('U1')[:, 4:6].view('U2').squeeze().astype(int)
```

The individual steps are like this:

1. `[:, None]` adds a dimension. You're now working on a temporary array that's `(365, 1)`.
2. `.view('U1')` splits up the characters into separate elements. The array is now `(365, 8)`.
3. `[:, 4:6]` extracts the month characters. The array is now `(365, 2)`.
4. `.view('U2')` combines the month slice back into a single string. The array is now `(365, 1)`.
5. `.squeeze()` removes the unit dimension so you are back to `(365,)`, but now with 2-character strings. No copies of the data have been made up to this point.
6. `.astype(int)` converts your strings into integers, so you have an array of 365 integers.

You can now get each month directly into dictionary comprehension:

```
rain_dict = {month: np.flatnonzero(mos == month) for month in range(1, 13)}:
```

At time of writing, you will have to get the `main` branch from the [numpy GitHub repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) and build it yourself. The change has been merged in, but release 1.23.0 is not publicly available yet. I will update the answer when it is.

---

I am also currently working on a function called `np.char.slice_` in [PR #20694](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694). That will allow the same integer array to be created as

```
mos = np.char.slice_(Date_np, 4, 6).astype(int)
```

---

Based on your comments and the fact that the array is 365 elements long, I strongly suspect that you are overcomplicating things. If the days are in order, the first 31 are going to be January, the next 28 February, etc. You don't really need the indices, just the lengths of the months. Of course it's impossible to tell (and out of scope for this one question), without seeing your actual usecase.